# Oracle SQL inserting a date into a table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
INSERT INTO Booking(BOOKING_ID, TRIP_DETAILS, DATE_HIRE, DESTINATION, NO_OF_PASSENGERS)
VALUES ('01', 'Bus group', '17-07-18', 'Paradise', '4');
```

This is an example, say booking table exists and the date_hire is written as

```
Date_Hire date NOT NULL,
```

Is the date format incorrect? it tells me the month is not valid, so I went to tools, preference, nls and my date format is DD-MON-RR, so I did make an error the way I inserted it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend using the `DATE` keyword with YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
INSERT INTO Booking (BOOKING_ID, TRIP_DETAILS, DATE_HIRE, DESTINATION, NO_OF_PASSENGERS)
    VALUES ('01', 'Bus group', DATE '2018-07-17', 'Paradise', 4);
```

Presumably, `NO_OF_PASSENGERS` is a number.  Don't use single quotes for numbers.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.